# What would be the equivalent of "Hala Madrid" for the Barça team?

Tags: deportes

I know Real Madrid fans say "*Hala Madrid*" to support the Real Madrid team.

What do F.C. Barcelona supporters say? Is there any instantly recognizable and distinctive phrase or chant, either in Spanish or in Catalan?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about sporting slogans.

Comment: This question isn't about the Spanish language--it's about what a local team uses as their slogan/chant.

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative, in catalan, and widely used is *Força Barça*. The chant is pronounced as "Forsa Barsa".

Answer (score 1):

Barcelona F.C. supporters would prefer to say it in *Catalan* rather than Spanish. Their chant is

> Visca Barça or Visca el Barça (which means *Viva el Barça / Long live Barça*)

The "ç" is pronounced /S/  `Visca el Barsa`

So there is not really a good answer in Spanish for your question.

If you wanted to support this or any other team in Spanish you could say.

> Arriba el Barça
>
> Viva el Barça

Comment: "Visca Barça" is never used. It sounds bad. But "Visca el Barça" is correct.

Comment: I just edited my answer so is better suited for this site, that is dedicated to Spanish Language, and not to other languages spoken in Spain.